# Is it possible for the router to re-direct to another IP?

Tags: router, ip

This might be a very noob question. Please forgive me if I'm not clear enough, for I don't thoroughly understand the processes / magic very well behind the network engineering.

Question:

Is it possible for the Router to change IP  address of the device that is connected to the Router.

For example : Say I live in Zimbabve,  but i wanna watch Netflix  on my mobile device. I will get a restriction message, If I try to access Netflix with my Zimbabve IP address. Would it be possible for me tweak the router, to make it change to the U.S IP once i connect to it with my mobile device?  I know there are some routers that support dd-wrt firmwares. Would that make any difference?

Thank you in advance and apologies for the noobness again.

Comment: Home networking is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is.. NO

DD-WRT might enable you to initiate a VPN from the router but ultimately if you want to watch Netflix with a US IP address so you get more "media" then you need to use either a proxy or a VPN to route your traffic to another service which then sends your traffic out from a IP/Server which is hosted in the U.S.

If Netflix is your issue then their is DNS workarounds to enable you to receive Netflix US (outside of US) but I think these forums aren't to talk about workarounds/hacks its a "Networking forum"

Ta